# Graph API: Check if feed post was made by a Page or User

Tags: json, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

When using the [/page/feed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/page/feed) endpoint in the Facebook Graph API I can't figure out **how to know if the post was made by a Page or a User**

Here's how I call the endpoint right now:

`HTTP GET https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/{page_id}/feed?fields=is_published,from,message`

This yields the following JSON response:

```
{
  "data": [
          {
            "from": {
              "name": "Chad Smith", # <-- This is a User
              "id": "806273209398023"
            },
            "message": "A really magical place! Best Christmas...",
            "id": "103988597020_1445496708809010"
          },
          {
            "from": {
              "name": "Tivoli", # <-- This is a Page
              "id": "103988597020"
            },
            "message": "Hello everybody...",
            "id": "103988597020_10154040865527021"
          },
  ]
}
```

How can I know if the post was from a Page or User **without making additional API calls?** I've tried using subfields, but can't figure out if they work on the `from` field.

Comment: The basic syntax for requesting "sub-fields" is described here, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#fieldexpansion

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using `?fields=from{name,about}` and marking it as a `Page` if the `from` JSON contains `about`.

**This is not the best solution**, but `about` is currently the only subfield of `from` that doesn't fail on `User`. (e.g. if I was using `?fields=from{fan_count}` the Graph API will fail for posts made by `User` objects.